# using webpack with laravel .env as flag

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, webpack

I use webpack to bundle my assets etc, but I have a config.js and within it it has variable as flags for my application. It would be easy if I use node.js, as it can read `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` but I'm using laravel, which used .env file.

how can I pass .env file into webpack.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

I've has a similar issue with my certain project. I've added the following line in the top of my `webpack.mix.js` file in the project root directory.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

My am using `"laravel/framework": "5.4.*"` and `"laravel-mix": "^1.4.2"`

Hope this might help.